# Exported GLTF plays too fast

Tags: keyframes, gltf

I have a project going that has a few animations and am able to export as a gltf with textures and everything looks fine. Im using the standard Microsoft 3d viewer, however, when It exports, the animation plays too fast. Before, I was able to export just fine but now, when I export, the animation plays too fast. I wonder if it is a setting or something I changed? the animation length has always been 371 frames. Before I had the problem it still was 371 frames. Any Idea on what this might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The glTF exporter is required to convert "frames" to "seconds" on the way to glTF.

Try choosing a lower frame rate, that should space out the number of seconds listed in the exported glTF file.

[image: screenshot of FPS Selector in Blender]

Comment: I tried this and it worked great! Thank you so much for the answer!!

Comment: One other note: the glTF exporter [does not currently](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues/387) (v3.2.1) use the "Frame Start" settings to offset the animations. So, an animation whose first keyframe is on the default "first" frame, frame 1, will start "late" in glTF. You want to ensure that your first animation keyframe is on frame 0.